# Update checkbox in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have check box like this:

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
  <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
      <input type="hidden" name="type" value="0">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxPrimary1" name="type" @if($role->type == 1) checked @endif>
      <label for="checkboxPrimary1">root</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

in controller:

```
$role = Role::find($id);
$role->type = $request->has('type');
$data = $request->all();
$role->update($data);
```

when the checkbox value is 1 then I can edit, but when the checkbox value is 0 then I get the error: SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1 (SQL: update `user_roles` set `type` = 0, `user_roles`.`updated_at` = 2021-10-10 15:48:36 where `id` = 1)

the type of the field in the database table  - enum('0','1')

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the value `'0'` datatype does not match the `MySQL datatype`.

> You can alter your database column datatype from enum to varchar or
> string.

`MYSQL: ALTER TABLE [user_roles] MODIFY COLUMN [type] VARCHAR(50)`

Or Even you can try with `laravel migration.`